# Optimize EditText Syntax Highlighting ( Spannable )

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android code editor, but when I apply syntax highlighting to it, it gets very laggy, is there any way to optimize it?

Here is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     scriptEditor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 applySyntax(s);
             }
         };
     }
     public void applySyntax(Spannable spannable) {
         matchz = WORDPat.matcher(spannable);
         while (matchz.find()) {
             Integer color = null;
             if (StringKeyword.contains(matchz.group())) {
                 color = Integer.valueOf(keyColor);
                 type = "keyword";
             }
             if (StringKeyword2.contains(matchz.group())) {
                 color = Integer.valueOf(keyColor2);
                 type = "keyword";
             }
             if (StringKeyword3.contains(matchz.group())) {
                 color = Integer.valueOf(keyColor3);
                 type = "keyword";
             }
             if (color != null) {
                 spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color.intValue()), matchz.start(), matchz.end(), 0);
                 color = null;
             } else {
                 spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), matchz.start(), matchz.end(), 0);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```